# Flutter - SQFlite query of period between two dates does not return data

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

I'm performing a database query from a Flutter application in which I need to bring records in the period between two dates. However, the query does not return records even though there are records saved for this period.

The query below returns zero records:

```
     final List<Map<String, dynamic>> records = await db.rawQuery(
     'SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE created BETWEEN 2022-07-17 AND 2022-08-16');
```

Attempting not to use the BETWEEN clause as below did not work either

```
     final List<Map<String, dynamic>> records = await db.rawQuery(
     'SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE created >= 2022-07-17 AND created <= 2022-08-16');
```

I also emphasize that the "created" column of the "vehicles" table stores String dates in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD and that the console does not report any syntax errors, it just does not working

Comment: you find solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you haven't added quotes in date.
So it should look like this:

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> records = await db.rawQuery(
     "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE created BETWEEN '2022-07-17' AND '2022-08-16'");
```

or like this:

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> records = await db.rawQuery(
     "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE created >= '2022-07-17' AND created <= '2022-08-16'");
```